# Why does my movement speed drop when my camera points down?

Tags: unreal-engine5, unreal-development-kit, unrealscript

My movement speed drops when I look down. I tried using the provided movement code template, but it didn't resolve the issue. Here's the code:

```
// Fill out your copyright notice in the Description page of Project Settings.


#include "CPPMainPlayer.h"

ACPPMainPlayer::ACPPMainPlayer() : Super()
{
    SpringArm = CreateDefaultSubobject<USpringArmComponent>(TEXT("SpringArmComponent"));
    SpringArm->SetupAttachment(RootComponent);
    SpringArm->TargetArmLength = 300.0f;
    SpringArm->bUsePawnControlRotation = true;

    Camera = CreateDefaultSubobject<UCameraComponent>(TEXT("MainCamerea"));
    Camera->SetupAttachment(SpringArm);
    Camera->bUsePawnControlRotation = false;
    
    bUseControllerRotationPitch = false;
    bUseControllerRotationYaw = false;
    bUseControllerRotationRoll = false;


}

void ACPPMainPlayer::SetupPlayerInputComponent(UInputComponent *MyPlayerInput)
{
    Super::SetupPlayerInputComponent(MyPlayerInput);

    MyPlayerInput->BindAxis("MoveForwardBackward", this, &ACPPMainPlayer;::MoveForwardBackward);
    MyPlayerInput->BindAxis("MoveRightLeft", this, &ACPPMainPlayer;::MoveRightLeft);

    MyPlayerInput->BindAxis("Turn", this, &ACPPMainPlayer;::AddControllerYawInput);
    MyPlayerInput->BindAxis("Look", this, &ACPPMainPlayer;::AddControllerPitchInput);

    MyPlayerInput->BindAction("Jump", IE_Pressed, this, &ACPPMainPlayer;::Jump);
    MyPlayerInput->BindAction("Jump", IE_Released, this, &ACPPMainPlayer;::StopJump);
   
}

void ACPPMainPlayer::MoveForwardBackward(float Value)
{
    FVector Direction = FRotationMatrix(Controller->GetControlRotation()).GetScaledAxis(EAxis::X);
    AddMovementInput(Direction, Value);
}
a
void ACPPMainPlayer::MoveRightLeft(float Value)
{
    FVector Direction = FRotationMatrix(Controller->GetControlRotation()).GetScaledAxis(EAxis::Y);
    AddMovementInput(Direction, Value);
}

void ACPPMainPlayer::Jump()
{
    bPressedJump = true;


}

void ACPPMainPlayer::StopJump()
{
    bPressedJump = false;
}
```

Comment: Imagine walking forward in real life. Think of having a consistent stride, and on a mission to go somewhere. That would set the movement speed (velocity) that you were traveling. 


Now; look down and still try to focus on going to where you want to go. Naturally you will slow because you are looking DOWN, and not forward.


best stab at trying to explain it. It has nothing to do with your code. If anything, and you wanted to maintain speed consistently regardless of looking down or up or forward, you can add do several diff checks and create a velocity 'booster' to find that balance?